# How do i provide password for su command while using net/telnet in ruby

Tags: ruby, scripting, telnet

I am using Net/TELNET to connect to remote host trying to run su command in order to get root privilage. This is how I am doing it

```
require 'net/telnet'

localhost = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => "192.147.217.27",
                             "Timeout" => 50,
                             "Prompt" => /[$%#>] \z/n)
localhost.login("dvsdkrp", "dvsdkvrp") { |c| print c }
localhost.cmd("cd /home/dvsdkrp/workdir/smruti") { |c| print c }
localhost.cmd("su") { |c| print c }
localhost.puts("passwd"){ |c| print c }
```

I am able to login and able to do smruti directory but when I use su command it takes me to the password prompt but then I get this error, even after I changed the Timeout parameter to 150

```
Password: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/telnet.rb:552:in `waitfor': timed out
while waiting for more data (Timeout::Error)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/telnet.rb:679:in `cmd'
        from tel.rb:7
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you _really_ sure you want to send your root password unencrypted? Why do you not use SSH instead?

Comment: pafcu that is not a problem for me means i do n't have problem sending root password unenrypted

Comment: and i tried ssh also but am getting some authenication failed error

Comment: I would setup SSH keys so you can drop into root without a password.  Another option would be using Expect instead of Net::Telnet.

Comment: Thanks Jason but why am not able to make su command run sucessfully and prompted to password prompt but after that its giving error

Comment: "Hi" is spelt with one "i", and "i" is capitalized. Also, indent code by four spaces so that it gets highlighted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt you specify when you create the Telnet object is the one its going to look for before it runs its next command.  If you are timing out then I think its because its not seeing the prompt it expects.  If you use the Match option when you send the 'su' command, you can specify a prompt specifically for this command.

```
su_prompt = "Password: "
localhost.cmd("String" => "su", "Match" => /#{su_prompt}/) { |c| print c }
localhost.cmd("passwd")
```

This new prompt is only used for the current command.  The originally specified prompt is still in affect for the rest of the session.

Comment: But D in which line i shoud provide password

Comment: after the 'Match' line is executed, the telnet session will wait for input after it sees the temporary prompt.  At this point you can send it your password.  (3rd line in the code sample)

Comment: undefined local variable or method `su' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: D am getting this error now when trying to execute Match line

Comment: You genius ,but could you please Explain what was the problem before i still did n't get what was the problem before